# How can I do complex twitter searches?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to search `#hashtag1 OR #hashtag2 OR (from:user1 OR from:user2) -term1 -term2`

But the user searches don't work. Any help?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available search operators are described here:

http://search.twitter.com/operators

You can also use this form:

http://search.twitter.com/advanced

to create a query you need.

If you still need help, please post exact example of the query which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

have you read [search documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) ?

Your syntax `from:` does not seem to exist.